# Slicing an Array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am having trouble finding a matlab function to slice an element out of an array.

For example:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to take out on element of this array, say the element 3:

```
B = [1, 2, 4]
```

Is there a matlab function for this or would I have to code the algorithm to construct a new array with all the elements of A except 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

```
index_of_element_to_remove = 3;
A(index_of_element_to_remove) = [];
```

now A will be `[1 2 4]`

If you want to remove more elements at the same time you can do:

```
index_of_element_to_remove = [1 3];
A(index_of_element_to_remove) = [];
```

now A will be `[2 4]`

Answer (score 4):

By value, which will remove all elements equal to 3

```
A(find(A==3)) = []
```

Or by index

```
A(3) = []
```

Comment: The first case is better as `A(A==3) = []`. See "logical indexing".

Comment: @Nzbuu, fully agree that my answer should also have included logical indexing, but what constitutes better is up for [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133712/logical-vs-numerical-array-in-matlab).

Comment: There should be no discussion in this case. If you're doing this sort of indexing, then adding an extra call to `find` is always redundant and will reduce performance. Both versions read as "Remove elements from A that are equal to 3."